# Modify class with c#

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following table

```
 PNLId  PNLParentId Operator    Sign    DisplayingOrder    PNLGrpId
     0        0         ~            1         1            1
     1       105        +           1         1            2
    11       20         +           -1        1            5
```

I use a class `Node` to get parent / child in a table

```
class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<Node> Children { get; set; }
    public Node()
    {
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Node: " + Operator + " " + Id + " " 
            + string.Join(",", Children.Select(x => x.Id));
    }
}
```

I got as result the following result

```
[50 Node: + 50 36,37]
[51 Node: + 51 49,50]
[52 Node: + 52 20,21,22]
[69 Node: + 69 56,57,58,59]
```

How can I modify the class node in order to children as pair(Sign, child) , something like that

```
[50 Node: + 50 (-1,36),(1,37)]
[51 Node: + 51 (-1,49),(-1,50)]
[52 Node: + 52 (1,20),(-1,21),(-1,22)]
[69 Node: + 69 (-1,56),(-1,57),(1,58),(1,59)]
```

Comment: sign is missing in your class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement `ToString` like following:

```
return "Node: " + Operator + " " + Id + " " + 
       string.Join(",", Children.Select
                         (x => string.Format("({0},{1})", x.Sign, x.Id)));
```

Comment: Although it is the right thing to do eventually, this code wouldn't compile given the `Node` class the asker has presented ( there is no `Sign` property even though there exists a `Sign` column ) -- Oh, I'm sorry -- it was you who also pointed that out in the comment... My bad :)

Answer (score 1):

For you exact purposes please consider the following steps:

- Step 1 - Add the `Sign` property to your class

  ```
  class Node
  {

      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int? ParentId { get; set; }
      public string Operator { get; set; }
      public Node Parent { get; set; }
      public IList<Node> Children { get; set; }

      // HERE WE GO
      public int Sign { get; set; }

      ...

  }
  ```
- Step 2 - Determine what is the connection between the table which you entitled "the following" and the `Node` class. Where exactly in your code is it stipulated that the `Id` property is the .NET manifestation of the `PNLId` column ?
- Step 3 - Once the question of Step 2 is answered you must recreate the same effect for the `Sign` property .. `Sign` column relationship
- Step 4 - Alter the `ToString` method like so:

  ```
  class Node
  {
      ...

      public override string ToString()
      {
          return "Node: " + Operator + " " + Id + " " 
              + string.Join(",", Children.Select(x => string.Format("({0}, {1})", x.Sign, x.Id)));
      }
  ```

  }

**Note**: check the modification of the `Children.Select` lambda argument:

```
Children.Select(x => string.Format("({0}, {1})", x.Sign, x.Id))
```